# SAPUI5 add description / tooltip for a select element

Tags: sapui5

I want to show some default text to a Select item. Its should show something like `Select your...`. I could not find something like a tooltip property for that purpose.

Currently I create some item with the text `Select your...` and then I select its key while init of the view. The item should not be selectable. I think there is no event for the Select which is fired when the Select is opened so I could remove this default item then. So does someone have a better idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select input has a tooltip property. Alternatively, you can have an item in your list that you could set as not selectable so that the user cant select it. The code below shows this in an XML view.

```
<Select width="18rem" selectedKey="1" tooltip="Select something from list">
    <items>
        <core:Item key="1" text="Select Something"  enabled="false"/>
        <core:Item key="2" text="Item 2"/>
        <core:Item key="3" text="Item 3"/>
        <core:Item key="4" text="Item 4"/>
    </items>
</Select>
```